# В чем ошибка? Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean?

Tags: php, while

Понимаю, что ошибка в том, что переменная типа bool, но не могу представить другого варианта реализации этой функции.

---

Traceback: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /templates/generation.php on line 15

---

***15 строка:***

```
function generation_head_menu ($mysqli) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `topic`";
    $resSQL = $mysqli -> query($sql);
    ?>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Главная</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <?php
                    while ($rowTopic = $resSQL -> fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./topic.php?id_topic='. $rowTopic["id"] .'">'. $rowTopic['name'].'</a></li>';
                    }                  
                ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? В чем ошибка вам известно.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как её исправить? Другого варианта реализации этой функции, кроме как написанной выше я не вижу!